# Assigning a version number to a DLL created using CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, dll

I have a method that creates a DLL from a .cs file that is based on the code found [here on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655).

Using that code, is there any way to specify the version number of the DLL that gets generated? Right now it's always 0.0.0.0. I can't find a property or constructor that I can call to specify the version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are compiling from a source file, have you tried just adding the Reflection namespace and the version attributes to the top of your .cs file before compiling it?

```
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```